# Filter an array of object based on key name of the object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```js
var data = [
    {
        abc: { name:"abc" }
    },
    {
        new_abc:  {name:"hello" }
    },
    {
        def: { name:"def" }
    },
    {
        ghi: { name:"ghi" }
    },
    {
        new_ghi: { name:"world" }
    },
    {
        new_jkl: { name:"javascript" }
    },
    {
        lmn: { name:"lmn" }
    },
];
```

I want only the objects that have a key *whose name starts with "new"*. In the above array, I have 3 such objects.

I want the output to be this:

```js
[
    {
        new_abc:{name:"hello"}
    },
    {
        new_ghi:{name:"world"}
    },
    {
        new_jkl:{name:"javascript"}
    },
]
```

Comment: You want to filter them out or only leave them?

Comment: filter them out

Comment: So, the output should be the opposite of what you show, then.

Comment: So there are two things here. First you need to write a function that checks if an object has a key starting with "new". Then you can use that function in a call to Array.filter. Good luck. :-)

Comment: I dont know if i worded it correctly but i want the output as shown above. I want another array which will only have the data with key value whose names start with "new" as shown above.

Comment: "filter out" = "remove". I've edited the question to clarify the requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following,

```js
var data = [
 {
  abc:{name:"abc"}
 },
 {
  new_abc:{name:"hello"}
 },
 {
  def:{name:"def"}
 },
 {
  ghi:{name:"ghi"}
 },
 {
  new_ghi:{name:"world"}
 },
 {
  new_jkl:{name:"javascript"}
 },
 {
  lmn:{name:"lmn"}
 }
]


res = data.filter(item => Object.keys(item).some(key => key.indexOf('new') === 0));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want only the objects that have a key whose `name starts with "new"`

You can use `Array#filter` combined with [String.prototype.startsWith()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) like this way.

```js
const data = [{abc:{name:"abc"}},{new_abc:{name:"hello"}},{def:{name:"def"}},{ghi:{name:"ghi"}},{new_ghi:{name:"world"}},{new_jkl:{name:"javascript"}},{lmn:{name:"lmn"}}];

console.log(data.filter(item => Object.keys(item)[0].startsWith('new')));
```

> The `startsWith()` method determines whether a string begins with the
> characters of a specified string, returning `true` or `false` as
> appropriate.